# Encoding and decoding timestamps per frame using libav* into mp4

Tags: python, ffmpeg, video-capture, libav

I am writing a program for recording and playing back video together with another program that is connected to a piece of hardware we sell. This other program gathers data from hardware, which contains "timestamp" counters at a fixed sampling rate.

I am looking for a way to encode these timestamps (either raw or converted to unix) into the outputted mp4 file. The main reason being that the video stream might only start getting saved a few minutes into the hardware acquisition

Recording:

```
                timestamp
Main program --------------->  Video program
  |                                 |
  |                                 |
  v                                 v
Save hardware data               Save frame data
  and timestamp                    and timestamp

  |                                 |
  |                                 |
  v                                 v
Custom data format                .mp4 file
```

Post processing analysis:

```py
for i in range(0,datalen):
    hardwareData, timestamp = readHardwareFile()
    frame, timestamp = readMP4()

    myData[timestamp].hardware = hardwareData
    mydata[timestamp].video = frame

analyze(myData)
```

The goal being that when a I want to playback in VLC, or with OpenCV, I have access to timestamps for each frame.

I currently save it as a separate text file with timestamp and frame #, but I'm wondering if there is a more standardized way to do this.

Comment: mp4 does not have a standard way to timestamp every frames other than it time relative to the previous frame. You can set the "Created Time" field in the MP4. then the calculate each frame timestamp as `created Time + sum of duration of all previous frames`.

Comment: Isn't the optional 'prft' box used for timestamp info?